# async and await not returning to caller as expected

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a simple `async` and `await` example I'm trying to work through and the execution is not returning to the caller as I expect. Here is the top level method:

```
protected async void MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task longRunningTask = LongRunningOperationAsync();
  DoOtherStuff1();
  DoOtherStuff2();
  DoOtherStuff3();
  await longRunningTask;
}
```

Here is the `LongRunningOperationAsync` method which does not work as expected and runs synchronously:

```
 private async Task LongRunningOperationAsync()
 {
   var myValues = await GetStuffViaLongRunningTask();
   //Code to work with myValues here...
 }
```

Here is the definition of `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask`

```
private async Task<IList<MyClass>> GetStuffViaLongRunningTask()
{

    //...Calls to get and build up IList<MyClass>
    return results;

}
```

The problem is the above code does **not** return to the caller and begin running the `DoOtherStuff1();` method as I would expect. However, instead of calling my own method and replacing it with a call to `await Task.Delay(10000);` like all the simple examples show, ***the code works as expected:***

```
 private async Task LongRunningOperationAsync()
 {
   //Returns to caller as expected:
   await Task.Delay(10000);
 }
```

The caller using the code above has `longRunningTask` with a `WaitingForActivation` as its status instead of `RanToCompletion`, showing it is still processing.

You might say my `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask()` method runs so quickly and I just can't see the results. However it always takes between 3-7 seconds to run and you can tell when debugging that the call is blocking and *synchronous*.

What am I doing incorrectly here, so that my call to `LongRunningOperationAsync()` is not working asynchronously when reaching the `await` word to call `LongRunningOperationAsync` within that method?

Comment: Where's the definition for `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask`?

Comment: @neoistheone - I added it to the post. It too has the `async` defined.

Comment: So one issue with what you posted was that we don't know anything about the calls inside this method. If those calls are *synchronous* then the `Task` doesn't get returned *until the method completes* and thus the entire stack would run **synchronously.**

Comment: 2 things here - 1. I tried _top to bottom_ all the way to the end making all calls in the chain have `async` and `await` and I still didn't see the proper result. 2. By the time I'm this deep in the call stack I don't care if the calls inside of `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask` run synchronously as long as execution returned to the caller upon hitting the `await` keyword when actually calling this method. Make sense? Basically I don't care if once `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask()` is called it is run synchronously, but the `await` word on it should have returned already, correct?

Comment: Using the `async/await` pattern, you don't have the luxury of *not caring.* Anytime the code is *synchronous* it will execute *synchronously*. In other words, if you're going to build an `async` method, and you want it to return control, you need to *make sure it gets to the `return` statement to return a `Task`* if you want it to execute *asynchronously.*

Comment: @atconway When we say, "async all the way down" we don't just mean have all of the methods marked as `async`, it's about them *actually being asynchronous*.  Having a synchronous method just marked as `async` doesn't really help.  A method marked as `async` can be synchronous, and a method without `async` can still be asynchronous.  "I don't care if the calls inside of GetStuffViaLongRunningTask run synchronously"  But you should, because it's important (as per the previous point) that the entire call chain be asynchronous for it to work.

Comment: The code will only return to the caller before the end of the method if the caller is on a UI thread and it will only return on await points.

Comment: @PauloMorgado The caller doesn't need to be on a UI thread for control to be returned to them.  Control will always be returned to the caller when the method is called, either the first time the method awaits or when it ends/returns.

Comment: It's actually on the presence of a `SynchronizationContext`, which, as far as I know, only happens for UIs. At the end of each await the continuation will be posted to the synchronization context. Other than that, the execution will be blocked until the executing task completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `//...Calls to get and build up IList<MyClass>` is synchronous CPU bound work, the issue there is that `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask` won't return until it either ends, or hits its first `await` call.  You should be getting a compiler warning on that method as it's an `async` method that doesn't have an `await` in it.

Instead, the method simply shouldn't be `async`, to clearly indicate to it's callers that it's synchronous work.  Just adjust the signature to:

```
private IList<MyClass> GetStuffViaLongRunningTask()
```

Then when calling it use `Task.Run` to ensure that the long running CPU bound work is done in another thread:

```
private async Task LongRunningOperationAsync()
{
    var myValues = await Task.Run(() => GetStuffViaLongRunningTask());
    //Code to work with myValues here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend for breaking down what I was trying to say!

Comment: I ran to this (as it looked correct), but I'm getting the following error: `Cannot resolve method Run(IList<myClass>), candidates are: System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run (System.Action) (in class Task), System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run (System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>) (in class Task)`

Comment: @atconway I altered it to one that doesn't have an ambiguity.

Comment: That did it, nice job :) So it is proper to still leave `LongRunningOperationAsync()` marked as `async` correct? Also is the lesson here, that unless every call all the way to the bottom is marked as `async` with `await` keywords, it will be blocking usless using the method you described?

Comment: @atconway `LongRunningOperationAsync` is a logically asynchronous method, so yes, it should be marked as `Async`.  As for the lesson here, the lesson is that you need to understand that just because a method uses the `async` keyword doesn't *necessarily* make it asynchronous, and doesn't mean it automatically runs on another thread.  It does nothing more than allow the use of the `await` keyword.  For a method to truely be asynchronous it needs to return to it's caller very quickly, and what it returns is an object that indicates when it's actually done (the `Task`).

Comment: Yeah I don't think I was falling into that pitfall (_"just because a method uses the async keyword doesn't necessarily make it asynchronous"_ - read that 10x in tutorials). If I typed it that way, that wasn't the case. I'm just trying to determine if I have a call that in turn calls 4 other methods sequentially downstream, they all have to have `async` and `await` or the entire call up the chain acts synchronously, correct? It appears if I don't have that setup, than I have to explicitly use `Task.Run()` to have the `await` return, correct?

Comment: @atconway As I said before, it's not about them having or not having the `async` keyword, it's about them *actually being asynchronous*.  You can have an asynchronous method that doesn't use `async` or `await`, and you can have a method that uses `async` and `await` and that isn't asynchronous.  `async` helps make it easier to write asynchronous methods, but just puttnig it there doesn't, in and of itself, make everything magically asynchronous.

Comment: Ok, so I think I'm getting it. The `async` and `await` act like placeholders but do nothing on their own. If I don't spawn my own thread, background thread, parallel task, etc. within those keywords mean nothing and do nothing?

Comment: @atconway `async`, by itself, does nothing but allow the method to contain `await` calls within it, and also wraps the result into a task.  `await` actually does stuff; it causes the current execution to stop and adds a continuation to the awaited task which will continue execution where it left off.  When you call an `async` method it will execute synchronously until it hits it's first `await` call.  Thus an `async` method with no `await` is really just a synchronous method.

Comment: Shoot I give up - my understanding is going in circles (not your fault, thanks for helping). That's back to my OP. _"`await` actually does stuff; it causes the current execution to stop and adds a continuation to the awaited task which will continue execution where it left off. When you call an async method it will execute synchronously until it hits it's first await call."_  So that's back to "why didn't my `await` keyword:" _"causes the current execution to stop and adds a continuation to the awaited task which will continue execution where it left off"_ as you state.

Comment: What he means by "actually being asynchronous" could more specifically be described as "actually returns a Task object".  There are many other asynchronous methods that spawn new threads or queue work items in the thread pool but Async/Await only recognizes the Task class.  Async/Await are technically just syntactic sugar.  In .NET 4.0 you can accomplish the same things with simply using Tasks and functions that return tasks.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Actually being asynchronous means more than just that though.  He has a method that returns as task, but does its work synchronously.  The key point is *returning to the caller right away*, and doing the "real work" after you have returned to your caller.  You can do that with `await`, with the older Task based model, with events, with callbacks, etc.  You don't *need* to use `Task`, although it is nice.

Comment: If you take a look at my example code in my answer you would see what an awaitable method looks like when implemented in .NET 4.0.  In .NET 4 you would have to call `Wait` or `ContinueWith` on the return value of this method, but with .NET 4.5 you can use async/await keywords for prettier looking code.  The same method doesn't have to be updated, it doesn't have to be marked with `async` in order for it to be awaited.

Comment: @Servy You can't await a function which does not return a Task object.

Comment: And yes you're right, when you return a task you have to make sure that the bulk of your work is actually executed in the Task callback.  That's just common sense.  In his example he was asynchronously waiting for 10000 milliseconds but running everything else beforehand synchronously.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Actually, interestingly enough, that's not true.  You can `await` any object with a `GetAwaiter()` method that return an object that conforms to a certain pattern (`Task` has such a method).  Regardless, what I said was that an object doesn't need to return a task to be `asynchronous`, which is true, although admittedly it's very hard to mix and match different styles of asynchrony; it's better to be consistant.

Comment: @TrevorElliott You say it's common sense, but it wasn't to the OP, not knowing that was at the heart of his problem, thus calling it out explicitly is an important thing to do.

Comment: @Servy That is interesting.  But to say you can await anything asynchronous is still too broad and confusing.  *None* of the other asynchronous implementations in .NET that you can find like IAsyncResult pattern (BeginSomething and EndSomething methods), the BackgroundWorker, Delegate.BeginInvoke, and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem support the async/await pattern.

Comment: @TrevorElliott I never said you can await anything asynchronous.  I said there are many different ways to make a method asynchronous and using `async` and `await` is just one of them.  A method can be asynchronous without the use of `async` or `await`.  Such a method may not be able to be awaited, but it's still asynchronous.  It's important to understand what "asynchronous" means, outside of just the context of `await`.

Comment: I think it's best to sum up the process of creating your own awaitable asynchronous method is to summarize 3 steps: 1) Create a task object. 2) Start the task. 3) Return the task.  Some of the async/await syntactic sugar confuses what's really going on behind the scenes, but that is what you do.  Starting the task inside the method where you create it is not enforced but it's the de facto standard.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Once again, a method need to use the Task based model to be asynchronous.  A method that does that is asynchronous, but methods can not do that and also be asynchronous.  An asynchronous method *in the task based model*, looks like that.

Comment: That's what I meant, since the asker did have async and await in his question title.  :)

Comment: So the magic I was missing (and was this answer) is "2) Start the task" (via `Task.Run()`) and also explained as: "you have to make sure that the bulk of your work is actually executed in the Task callback"? In a nutshell, I was not using the returned `Task` object to _truly_ make the method asynchronous?

Comment: @atconway The problem was that your "construct the task" step involved doing lots of long running work, and that you didn't return the task until after your work was done, rather than starting up some work that will be completed at a later point in time and then returning the task *right away*.   If the long running operation is CPU bound work the way to get a task *right now* representing it's completion *some time later* is to use `Task.Run`.  If your long running work was a network call then there are APIs that will create such as task *right now* for work that *finishes later*.

Comment: @atconway I think you missed step #1 too.  You never created your own task!  You only created a task using `Task.Delay()` which creates a task of its own and returns it.  But all that task was doing was sleeping for 10000 milliseconds, it wasn't doing any of your work.  You had code that was written "do all this stuff synchronously, then asynchronously wait 10000ms for no reason"...  Task.Run creates a task for you which is one of the many ways of starting an async task.

Comment: Ok now I think I'm getting it better. I never created a `Task` that would return quickly. Both `Task.Delay()` and `Task.Run()` solve that issue. By the way that `Task.Delay()` code was just used as a test to prove execution would return to the caller. The reason I now understand _it was returning_ was because it returned that `Task` object right away. My code had no `Task` being returned until the end of the method since that is what it returned: `Task`

Comment: @atconway More or less.  Technically in your code you just hit an `await` keyword in both cases, but `await`, as I said before, results in the current executing method ending and returning to its caller.  In the method in which you use `Delay` you could have just simplified what happens a lot of you returned the task and didn't even mark the method as `async`.

Comment: Any suggestion on some good reading that speaks to what my misunderstanding was today so I can understand it even better? Problem is so many of the `async` and `await` examples are so simplistic, I miss the deeper explanations.

Comment: @atconway: If you have a synchronous method marked as `async`, the compiler will give you a warning explaining exactly what the problem is. Also, you may find [my tutorial](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Actually I had read your blog post and thought it was very good. In fact the `await Task.Delay()` code attempt in my OP came from your post.

Answer (score 1):

> `//...Calls to get and build up IList<MyClass>`

You need to show us which calls are being made.  If you want to use async/await with this structure then you need to make an async call.

If your `GetStuffViaLongRunningTask` function is not doing async calls then you can start a new task like the following:

```
private Task<IList<MyClass>> GetStuffViaLongRunningTask()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //...Calls to get and build up IList<MyClass>
        // You can make synchronous calls here
        return list;
    });
}
```